# "Allow from" in httpd-xampp.conf for ipv6?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I want to secure my virtual server so phpmyadmin can only be accessed from my laptop. I have the following code in httpd-xampp.conf,

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">  
        Order deny,allow                                                                             
        Deny from all                                                                                
        Allow from <my_ip_address>
</LocationMatch>
```

When I get to a new place, I usually google "what is my ip" and get an ip address (ipv4) and make change to the "Allow from" line and restart apache.
However, I got to this new place and "what is my ip" returns an ipv6 address. I put that in, it didn't allow me access. I searched "what is my ipv4" and get an ipv4 address, that didn't allow me access either.
The only way I can get it to work is to "Allow from all". But that defeats the whole purpose. Anyone knows what I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">                                                                              
        Require ip your_ipv6_address
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Did you enabled the *dual stack mode* in apache? One process for ipv4 devices and one for ipv6 ones

Comment: Don't know what dual stack mode in apache is. Searched online, some say to enable by listen to ipv6 address. But currently I have "Listen 80" in my httpd.conf file, how to listen to ipv6 address? I don't know how to find ipv6 address for the server, or what is ipv6 equivalent of localhost. It appears "Listen 80" only listens to ipv4.

Comment: Dual stack mode is when your apache server is serving both ipv4 and ipv6 clients. Try to add `Listen [2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea]:80` along with your current ipv4 conf, substituting the ipv6 address with your client address.

Comment: do you mean substituting the ipv6 address with my server address? do you know how to find my server ipv6 address? Currently it only says "Listen 80" which I assume is listen to localhost port 80 on ipv4? Or does it mean listen to any ipv4 on port 80?

Comment: Sure, sorry, my mistake. Try `Listen [::0]:80`. `Listen 80` should mean to listen on any ipv4 at the port 80. `Listen [::0]:80` is the same for ipv6. You can use them together, just put it after the first `Listen`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I got the following message when I try to start apache after adding "Listen [::0]:80". `[Tue Jun 06 20:53:28.994000 2017] [core:crit] [pid 11055] (EAI 9)Address family for hostname not supported: AH00077: alloc_listener: failed to set up sockaddr for ::0
AH00526: Syntax error on line 53 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:
Listen setup failed` Any idea what I did wrong? This is surprisingly difficult to search online. I spent quite a lot of time on google and didn't see any link talking about this. :(

Comment: It seems like your network interface is not configured for ipv6. Can you edit your question with the whole `httpd.conf`? Please post also the output of `ifconfig` and `cat /proc/net/if_inet6`. 
Furthermore, consider migrating the question to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I did a little more digging and it appears my server is not setup for ipv6. I have a virtual private server so I called the hosting company, and they told me the server I have can't work for ipv6. I have to upgrade to real private server to be able to use ipv6. So I guess I will give up on this issue. (I also tested on some website that confirms my website is not working with ipv6, whatever that means.) Thanks again for all your suggestions.